# Tor circuit selection

Tags: configuration, circuit, settings

Quick question - is it possible to 'exclude' or 'bypass' certain Tor Circuits?

Example: At this moment it shows the circuit as France - Netherlands - France. What I am wondering is, can I tell Tor to never use France in it's circuit selection? Reason being simple, France has notoriously slow servers and it slows down the whole browsing experience...

Comment: Did you try googling this?

Comment: Also France does not have slow servers. France actually is in the top three for fastest Tor relays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Settings in torrc:

```
StrictNodes 1
ExcludeNodes {fr}
```

Read more on how to configure your torrc file [here](http://uscyberlabs.com/blog/2012/09/17/tor-setup-torrc-file-configuration/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done by adding `ExcludeNodes {fr}` and `StrictNodes 1`, that said however...you should *never, ever* actually do this!

First of all, you can't stop your connection *traversing* France. If you pick a node in Italy and a node in Switzerland you may well traverse French networks.

Second of all, GeoIP is notoriously inaccurate and can be intentionally fooled. There are infact specific cases on the Tor network of nodes that lie about their location. For example [this Tor Node](https://globe.torproject.org/#/relay/BC630CBBB518BE7E9F4E09712AB0269E9DC7D626) according to GeoIP is supposedly in Liberia. *It's not in Libera!*

As such by excluding French nodes you are reducing the possible paths and exit points that you will use on the Tor network and harming your anonymity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sincerely. I will try something and see if it helps my case or not. May end up just leaving it alone in the end... Thanks again.