# Problem with tor as a Proxy

Tags: configuration, proxy

I need to watch an Australian channel on Youtube and for this to be possible I need an Australian ip. While I actually did make it work sometimes with tor+proxy, the IP I keep getting most of the times is the same for Australia and Netherlands. So when I try to access the site it says I'm in the Netherlands and obviously it doesn't work.
I've already set the `ExitNodes {AU} StrictNodes 1` and also `ExcludeExitNodes {NL}` to see if it would remove the nl ip from the list and it keeps the same.
Any way to fix this? Is there any option to set a permanent ip on tor?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/tor-circuit-selection/9746#9746) for some background but tl;dr:

If you and the server have different revisions of the GeoIP database you may potentially disagree about what country the IP is associated with. One *or* both of you may be wrong.

IP address and geolocation are, ultimately, unrelated.

As for setting a "permanent IP", Tor Browser achieves long term exits by using SOCKS authentication based on the top level domain and the `KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth` flag on the [`SOCKSPort`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SOCKSPort). This means that while you continue to use a website, Tor Browser will use the same circuit for it. Otherwise there are options like [`TrackHostExits`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#TrackHostExits).

You should take *great care* in not interfering with Tor's path selection you should not *want* to "set a permanent ip".