# Why do I seem to have different IP addresses at the same time?

Tags: exit-relays, ip-address, location

I edited the `torrc-defaults` file and added the line `ExitNodes {GB}` to get a UK exit node. (I myself am *not* in the UK.)

It seemed to work, here's what [dnsleaktest.com](http://dnsleaktest.com) tells me

[image]

However, other sites, like [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com) seem to disagree on where I am and what my IP is.

[image]

Google also thinks I'm in France. If I go to google.com, I am redirected to google.fr.

This is all within a single session. This happens even if I go to all these sites at the same time.

Why is this happening? I'm looking for a technical description of it's possible for different sites can think I'm in different places. (A solution to the problem would be cool, too.)

By the way, I'm using Tor Browser 5.5.5 on OS X 10.10.1.

**Update:** I've tried to add `StrictNodes 1` and `ExcludeNodes {fr}`, but it didn't change the output of whatismyip.com. Google.com did stop redirecting me to google.fr .

Comment: Duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11782/problem-with-tor-as-a-proxy/11795#11795 also without `StrictNodes` it will make connections from other exits. You should consider RTFM before making janky changes that you don't understand.

Comment: @canonizingironize Hey, thanks for the help! I did try searching for a dupe before asking, but that question eluded me. I'm not sure which "f*****g" manual you are referring to, but maybe [this one](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)? It's a bit long and technical for a non-savvy novice like me, I would think? Have you read the whole thing yourself? I find people are generally kind and helpful on SE, so I can usually seek some expert assistance here. I don't use Tor for anything sensitive or serious, so I'm not too worried about getting compromised.

Comment: @canonizingironize Please note, also, that my question is actually asking for *why* this is happening. Basically the technical reason. That's not mentioned in the other question. Just a small point. By the way, I've now added `StrictNodes 1` and `ExcludeNodes {fr}` to `torrc-defaults`, but I still get the same output from whatismyip.com . I even get the exact same IP. Google, though, doesn't redirect me to google.fr anymore :) Thanks again for your input!

Comment: Read the rest of my answer as to why IPs "country" might be reported entirely differently by different entities. There is no such thing as "GeoIP", thats not how the internet works.

Comment: @canonizingironize Cool, I'll take a look at it. Also, check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74080/321647

Comment: thats up to the admins. i think its a duplicate, i say its a duplicate. if admins disagree then they can handle it.

Comment: @canonizingironize Cool, thanks for helping! By the way, I'm still not sure how to get a UK IP . `StrictNodes 1` and `ExcludeNodes {fr}` didn't do it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UK IP" :)

Comment: @canonizingironize Allow me to rephrase that, then: I'm still not sure how to make websites "think" I'm browsing from the UK.

Comment: You need to find out their set of arbitrary IP to country mappings, then try to connect from an appropriate mapping to match what country they think it is.

Comment: @canonizingironize Also, there's the [UK Independence Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Independence_Party), but I'm sure that's not what you were talking about. </attempt-at-humour>

Comment: @canonizingironize That sounds like quite a task! Alright, let''s leave it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`ExitNodes {GB}
StrictNodes 1`

> **If StrictNodes is set to 1**, Tor will treat the ExcludeNodes option as a requirement to follow for all the circuits you generate, **even if doing so will break functionality for you**. **If StrictNodes is set to 0**, Tor will still try to avoid nodes in the ExcludeNodes list, but **it will err on the side of avoiding unexpected errors**. Specifically, StrictNodes 0 tells Tor that it is okay to use an excluded node when it is necessary to perform relay reachability self-tests, connect to a hidden service, provide a hidden service to a client, fulfill a .exit request, upload directory information, or download directory information.

StrictNodes means if your local GeoIP database says it's not GB it will hard-fail. Their GeoIP database may well disagree with yours, this is because there is no such thing as GeoIP. It's generated by scraping whois records and using the listed associated addresses to determine their location -- [no one would lie on the internet, right?](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/BC630CBBB518BE7E9F4E09712AB0269E9DC7D626)

*Edit:*

Furthermore, your Tor client *cannot* predict where it will exit the Tor network. It knows where to connect *into* the exit relay but this has absolutely no relation to where it will exit *from*. Some Exit relays will exit from entirely different address ranges than those that it runs it's `ORPort` on. Your client can only make decisions based on the address associated with it's advertised `ORPort` address.

Even *if* GeoIP weren't just some arbitrary listing that could be intentionally fooled the times that it didn't get it plain wrong, there is no guarantee that the times it gets it right it would even relate to where your traffic exits from.

This entire approach is folly, and the GeoIP-based restrictions is a misfeature.